# how to store image to phone gallery 

Tags: android

```
    /* now i want to save my image present in imageview to phone gallery */

    private Button button1;    
    private ImageView imageView1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);   
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);            
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {    
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
        if(v == button1) {    
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(PhoneImageGalleryActivity.this,PhoneImageGalleryActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);                
    }
```

Comment: Images added to the SDCARD are already scanned by the MediaScanner you shouldn't have to do anything special.

Answer (score 0):

If you save image in SD card and run `MediaScanner` it wwill automatically in gallery

Comment: i am not able to find code to save image to sdcard also.could u please send me any code

Comment: hear is something that definitely will help http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: no it will store image in Picture directory of your SD card and it will be visible in gallery

Comment: what difficulty you are facing?

Comment: i had finded solution in solving the problem.                         http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/2D-Graphics/DrawonPictureandsave.htm

Comment: i am not able to save view background to phone gallery

Comment: i am not getting what exactly you want

Comment: i am looking to paint on a view and store to phone gallery

Comment: using gesture? if so then i would recommended the example GestureBuilder  in the samples folder of your android-sdk. I am not sure but as far as i am concerned that will help you

Answer (score 0):

Images added to the SDCARD are already scanned by the MediaScanner you shouldn't have to do anything special.

Thumbnails are always being created when images are added. This is because the Thumbnail service is actually doing this very frequently/efficiently as data changes.